# How do I add data to a JSON file on this localhost site in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to add data to this localhost website so that when I refresh the page, the new data will have been added and will be in there permanently. So far, I have successfully parsed the JSON file and added the new data, but it appears that the HTTP post request doesn't work because the data isn't added onto the site.

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    // set the value of lat and long

    let latitude = location.latitude
    let longitude = location.longitude

    let parameters = ["lat": latitude, "lng": longitude]

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://10.0.0.133/~alexanderchoi/UserLocation.json") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
        }

            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                var parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserCoords].self, from: data)
                parsedJSON.append(Vac_Pass.UserCoords(lat: latitude, lng: longitude))
                let wer = try JSONEncoder().encode(parsedJSON)

                // prints data out with newly added data too
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: wer, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

    }.resume()

}
```

Thank you - all inputs are appreciated :D

Comment: Have you heard of a security protocol called sandbox?

Comment: Where does a guy named 'Vac_Pass' come from?